# "FormatException in property ... " error despite valid Expression Binding syntax

Tags: sapui5

I would like to display a sap.m.Button in case the value of two model properties are equal. It that possible via [expression binding](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0).

Bindings:

- `{user-management>/alias}`

  - value: `"TESTUSER"`
- `{recipe-service>Author/alias}`

  - value: `"TESTUSER"`

My attempts:

```xml
<Button xmlns="sap.m" visible="{= ${user-management>/alias} === ${recipe-service>Author/alias}}" />
<!-- or: -->
<Button xmlns="sap.m" visible="{= ${user-management>/alias} === ${recipe-service>Author/alias} ? true : false}"/>
```

The above attempts are not working resulting with the following console error:

> FormatException in property 'visible' of 'Element sap.m.Button#__button1': TESTUSER is not a valid boolean value
> Hint: single properties referenced in composite bindings and within binding expressions are automatically converted into the type of the bound control property, unless a different 'targetType' is specified. targetType:'any' may avoid the conversion and lead to the expected behavior.

I am not aware of using `targetType` for expression binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be using an OData V4 service. In that case, **replace `$` with `%`** within the [expression binding](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0) where the V4 OData model value is embedded but causes the above error.

Assuming the latter "`recipe-service`" model is `sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel`:

```xml
<Button xmlns="sap.m" visible="{= ${user-management>/alias} === %{recipe-service>Author/alias}}" />
```

See also the information about the automatic type determination in topics *[Changes Compared to OData V2 Model](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/abd4d7c7548d4c29ab8364d3904a6d74)* and *[Type Determination](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/53cdd55a77ce4f33a14bd0767a293063).*